# Linear stochastic differential equation solution proof

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

I'm studying from Daniel Revuz, Marc Yor - Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion book.
In particular, I'm having a hard time understanding a particular step into the proof of the Proposition 2.3 of the IX chapter - Stochastic Differential Equation.
Below the text of the proposition.

> The solution to the linear equation
> $$
> Y_t = H_t + \int_0^t Y_s \text{d}X_s
> $$
> where $H,X$ are two given continuous semimartingales is
> $$
> Y_t = \mathcal{E}(X)_t \left( H_0 + \int_0^t \mathcal{E}(X)_s^{-1} \left( \text{d}H_s - \text{d}\left<H,X \right>_s \right) \right)
> $$
> where $\mathcal{E}(X)_s = \exp(X_s - 1/2 \left<X \right>_s)$ is the stochastic exponential.

**Proof.** Let us compute $\int_0^t Y_s \text{d} X_s$ for $Y$ given in the statement:
$$
\int_0^t Y_s \text{d}X_s = H_0 \int_0^t \mathcal{E}(X)_s \text{d} X_s + \overbrace{\int_0^t \mathcal{E}(X)_s \left( \int_0^s \mathcal{E}(X)_u^{-1} (\text{d}H_u - \text{d}\left<H,X \right>_u)\right) \text{d}X_s}^{(\star)}.
$$
In the book's proof the $(\star)$ addend is written as:
$$
\int_0^t \mathcal{E}(X)_s \text{d}X_s \left( \int_0^s \mathcal{E}(X)_u^{-1} (\text{d}H_u - \text{d}\left<H,X \right>_u)\right) \overbrace{=}^{(\ast)}
$$
and to that addend the integration by parts is computed.

**My question is:** how was it possible to "move" the $\text{d}X_s$ and ignore the process
$$
\int_0^s \mathcal{E}(X)_u^{-1} (\text{d}H_u - \text{d}\left<H,X \right>_u)?
$$
**Edit.** From $(\ast)$ I get
$$
\overbrace{=}^{(\ast)}
-H_0 + H_0 \mathcal{E}(X)_t + \mathcal{E}(X)_t \int_0^t \mathcal{E}(X)_s^{-1} (\text{d}H_s - \text{d}\left<H,X \right>_s)
- \int_0^t \mathcal{E}(X)_s \left( \mathcal{E}(X)_s^{-1} \text{d}H_s - \mathcal{E}(X)_s^{-1} \text{d}\left<H,X \right>_s \right)
- \left<\mathcal{E}(X), \int_0^\cdot \mathcal{E}(X)_s^{-1} \text{d}H_s \right>_t
$$

Comment: Could you give the next few equations in the proof? It's possible that this is just a notation issue; I've seen people (in various contexts, namely physics) write integrals by putting the $dx$ term in the beginning, like $$\int dx f(x)$$

Comment: @AlanChung I edited the post at the end

Comment: I have looked into my copy of RY. It is exactly as Alan Chung says. $dX_s$ is moved to the front (for whatever reason) but nothing is ignored. Do the proof with your $\overbrace{\int_0^t\phantom{\quad\quad}\,dX_s}^{(\star)}$ notation if you like that better.

Comment: @KurtG. thanks for your comment. Anyway I also tried to read the proof adjusting the notation as I liked but I cannot see how the integration by parts formula is used. Can you give me more insights, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revuz & Yor write
$$
\int_0^t\mathcal{E}(X)_s\,\color{red}{dX_s} \left( \int_0^s \mathcal{E}(X)_u^{-1} (\,dH_u - \,d\left<H,X \right>_u)\right) 
$$
for
$$
\int_0^t\mathcal{E}(X)_s \left( \int_0^s \mathcal{E}(X)_u^{-1} (\,dH_u - \,d\left<H,X \right>_u)\right) \,\color{red}{dX_s}\
$$
which is what sometimes physicists do in multiple integrals with complicated integrand. We shall see below that it also is a smart way of grouping together
what belongs together:

With the abbreviations $M_t:=\mathcal{E}(X)_t$ and
$$
N_t:=\int_0^t \mathcal{E}(X)_u^{-1} (\,dH_u - \,d\left<H,X \right>_u)
$$
the integration by parts formula
$$
M_tN_t=\int_0^tN_s\,dM_s+\int_0^tM_s\,dN_s+\langle M,N\rangle_t
$$
gives
\begin{align}
&\int_0^t\underbrace{\color{red}{\mathcal{E}(X)_s\,dX_s}}_{dM_s}\underbrace{\left( \int_0^s \mathcal{E}(X)_u^{-1} (\,dH_u - \,d\left<H,X \right>_u)\right)}_{N_s}\\
&=\underbrace{\mathcal{E}(X)_t}_{M_t}\;\underbrace{\int_0^t \mathcal{E}(X)_u^{-1} (\,dH_u - \,d\left<H,X \right>_u)}_{N_t}\\
&-\int_0^t\underbrace{\mathcal{E}(X)_s}_{M_s}\;\underbrace{\left(\mathcal{E}(X)_s^{-1}\,dH_s - \mathcal{E}(X)_s^{-1}\,d\left<H,X \right>_s\right)}_{dN_s}\\
&-\left\langle \underbrace{\mathcal{E}(X)}_{M},\underbrace{\int_0^. \mathcal{E}(X)_u^{-1} (\,dH_u - \,d\left<H,X \right>_u)}_{N}\right\rangle_t
\end{align}
which is exactly what they wrote.

After having this book in my shelf now for 35 years or so I still find gems in it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I'm feeling dumb because I defined correctly the process $M_t$ and $N_t$  to apply the integration by part formula but I failed to write the $\int_0^t M_s \text{d}N_s$ correctly and the proof didn't come up! Thanks again!